# How do I identify the user of an incoming message in socket-io server?

Tags: node.js, authentication, socket.io

I am using nodejs socket-io (server) package. I got to know that I can use handshake data to  authenticate users during establishing connection. And I can add some attributes to that handshake data for later use as long as I can get the `socket` object.
But when handling `io.on` events, only data is passed as parameters.

```
io.on('some-channel', data => console.log(data));
```

I cannot get to know who sent this message. It is obviously not a good idea to let the client tell the server who he is.

An easy solution would be listening that channel for every connected socket:

```
io.sockets.on('connect', socket => {
    socket.on('some-channel', data => console.log(socket, data));
});
```

But when listening some channels and users connecting happens alternately, I have to listen all the channels defined previosly for new incoming users, and listen new channels for every currently connected users. That seems not to be a good practice.

So how do I identify the user of an incoming message, no matter in `io.on` event or any other better?

Comment: every user has socket. Socket has an ID. Emit the data as an object { id: socket.id, data: data }.

Comment: @AlbertS I see, then how do I prevent user emitting fake id? Or the id is not predictable?